# Why is the toString() method being called when I print an object?

Tags: java, object

I can't seem to understand why when  I use println method on the quarter object, it returns  the value of the toString method. I never called the toString method why am I getting the return value?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Quarter q = new Quarter();
        Nickel n = new Nickel();
        System.out.println(q);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}

public abstract class Money {
    private int value;

    public Money(int v) {
        value=v;
    }

    public abstract int getValue();

    protected int myValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract String toString();
}

public abstract class Coin extends Money {
    public Coin(int value) {
        super(value);
        System.out.println("I am a coin, my value is " + getValue());
    }
}

public class Quarter extends Coin {
    public Quarter () {
        super(25);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return myValue();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "A Quarter is "+getValue();
    }
}

public class Nickel extends Coin {
    public Nickel () {
        super(5);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return myValue();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "A "+this.getClass().getName()+ " is "+getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you suppose the string representation of your quarter object is? You cant just tell java to print your object.

Answer (score 18):

On Refering to java docs what i undestand is that,

When you call PrintStream class **print(obj) / println(obj)** method then internally it called **write** method with arguement as **String.valueOf(obj)** shown below :

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Now **String.valueOf(obj)** does the task of calling to String method as shown below :

```
 /**
 * Returns the string representation of the <code>Object</code> argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an <code>Object</code>.
 * @return  if the argument is <code>null</code>, then a string equal to
 *          <code>"null"</code>; otherwise, the value of
 *          <code>obj.toString()</code> is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `PrintStream.println` has an overload that takes an `Object`, and then calls its `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is how this function operates: it formats the primitive types for you, but when you pass it an object, it will call `.toString()` on it.

If you don't override it, it will output the default `.toString()` implementation (`Class@somenumber`) which is not really useful...

Comment: Oh I see! I never knew that. So if I pass an object in the arguments of the println method I will call the tostring method of that object by default. It does not seem to be useful and it contradicts what I learn about "you don't use a method unless you call it". But thanks for the info about println method. It seems rather sneaky for the println method to call the tostring method like that.

Comment: @NicholasKong: "You don't use a method unless you call it"; this is only true for non-override methods.  `toString` is an override of a base-class method, and so may be invoked by things that take a reference to the base class.

Comment: Well, maybe you prefer the C version which tries and prints everything as a 0-terminated `char *`? :p

Comment: Okay Thanks everyone! overridden methods such as toString gets  call no matter! i will bear in mind.

Comment: No, don't jump to conclusions like that. Like @OliCharlesworth says, the real reason is because `System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and when the `print()` method of this class is called with an Object as an argument, it will actually print the result of this object's `.toString()` method. Now, your object may _or may not_ override `.toString()`.

Comment: And finally, note that there is another case when an object's `.toString()` method is called "without your consent": it is when you build a string literal like, for instance: `"my object is " + myObject`.

Comment: "your object may or may not override .toString() " fge, are you saying it "may not override .toString method if that object does not extend a superclass? I will keep that in mind too about jumping to conclusions. My bad.

Comment: No, I say that you may choose to override it, or not. Your choice!

Comment: fge, hmm I tested it. Eclipse forces me to override .toString method if I inherit from a superclass apparently.

Answer (score 1):

When you are directly trying to print an object, by default it will call the `toString` method you need to override that `toString` method to print the attributes of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Because all classes in java are subclasses of java.lang.Object , so whenever you try to call System.out.println() method to print object, it calls the toString() method of Object class.

For Security Reasons the method prints a hashcode, not the values of that object,
but you have inherited that method in your class and extended its definition to print object values

```
public String toString() {
        return "A Quarter is "+getValue();
    }
```

So you get a return value.