# toString Method Call in Java

Tags: java, object, tostring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the toString() method being called when I print an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object)

I have this piece of code below. I understand everything else except the output using the **toString method in the Room Class** . In the **HotelMain** Class, I just called the **displayRooms Method** that was in the **Hotel Class**. But, when I ran the program, the toString output was shown in the console.

If I'm right toString() is the textual representation of the value in the object. But, I'm not sure where I called the toString method.

Can someone solve my dilemma? Thank You.

**Hotel Class**

```
public class Hotel {

private String hotelName;
private Room[] rooms;

public Hotel(String hotelName, int numberOfRooms) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
    this.rooms = new Room[numberOfRooms];
}

public void addRooms(Room room) {

    int position = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
        Room tempRoom = rooms[i];

        if (tempRoom == null) {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (position != -1) {
        rooms[position] = room;
        System.out.println("New room added at postion " + position);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Addition of room failed.");
    }
}

public void displayRooms() {

    System.out.println("The Hotel: " + this.hotelName + " has the following rooms.");

    for (int i = 0; i < this.rooms.length; i++) {
        Room tempRoom = rooms[i];
        if (tempRoom != null) {
            System.out.println(tempRoom);
        }
    }

}
```

**Room Class**

```
public class Room {

private int roomNumber;
private int numberOfBeds;
private boolean smokingOrNonSmoking;

public Room() {

}

public Room(int roomNumber, int numberOfBeds, boolean smokingOrNonSmoking) {
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
    this.numberOfBeds = numberOfBeds;
    this.smokingOrNonSmoking = smokingOrNonSmoking;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Room [roomNumber=" + roomNumber + ", numberOfBeds="
            + numberOfBeds + ", smokingOrNonSmoking=" + smokingOrNonSmoking
            + "]";
}
```

}

**Hotel Main**

```
public class HotelMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Hotel hotel = new Hotel("MahaRani Chain of Hotels", 10);
Room room1 = new Room(4, 2, true);
Room room2 = new Room(2, 1, false);
Room room3 = new Room(6, 3, true);
Room room4 = new Room(6, 4, false);

hotel.addRooms(room1);
hotel.addRooms(room3);
hotel.addRooms(room4);
hotel.addRooms(room2);

hotel.displayRooms();

}
```

}

**Console**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate topic and more information: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object

Answer (score 8):

```
Room tempRoom = rooms[i];
if (tempRoom != null) {
    System.out.println(tempRoom);
}
```

You have the above code in your `displayRooms()` method. It prints `tempRoom`, which is a reference of `Room`, and hence it calls `toString()` method overridden in the `Room` class.

Comment: +1, because you beat me by 1 sec. ;)

Answer (score 6):

when you call

```
System.out.println(tempRoom);
```

the `toString()` method of Room is automatically called on `tempRoom`.

Comment: +1 Because you got beaten up by 1 second. :)

Answer (score 5):

In this line

```
System.out.println(tempRoom);
```

this is the same as

```
 System.out.println(tempRoom.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`toString` is a special method of the `Object` class, here is its [description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

This method is widely used in those places when an object should be converted to textual representation. When you print an object to `PrintStream` (`System.out` in this case), this stream calls `toString` to convert this object to a string.