# How are these methods being used without being called?

Tags: java

I have this pared down set of class files as an example of OO.  They work perfectly but I do not understand how the `println` call from *WorkerTest.java* makes it all the way through *Worker.java* and to *Date.java*?   Both *Worker.java* and *Date.java* have `toString` methods but neither are explicitly called, but I can tell from the output that both are used.

How is this working or what concept should I be studying?

```
public class WorkerTest {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Date birth = new Date( 7, 15, 1922 );
      Worker worker = new Worker( birth );

      System.out.println( worker );
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Worker {
    private Date birthday;

    public Worker(  Date inboundBirthday ) {
      birthday = inboundBirthday;
    }

   public String toString() {
      return String.format( "Birthday: %s",  birthday );
   }
}
```

---

```
public class Date {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public Date( int inboundMonth, int inboundDay, int inboundYear ) {
        month = inboundMonth;
        day = inboundDay;
        year = inboundYear;
    }

    public String toString() {
       return String.format( "%d/%d/%d", month, day, year );
    }
}
```

---

Output:
`Birthday: 7/15/1922`

Comment: I'm sure some one else can describe it better, but, if the value your are writing isn't a `String`, Java will automatically call `toString` on the `Object`.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When println encounters a variable it tries to determine how it should be printed. It checks to see if the toString() method for the class in question has been overridden. So here's what's happening: println needs to print an instance of class worker, so it checks for the toString() method inside the Worker class. Inside the worker class it finds this line:

```
return String.format( "Birthday: %s",  birthday );
```

Now it must figure out how to print birthday. Since birthday is an instance of Date, it checks for Date's toString() method. The key thing in understanding all this is that Java's built in classes have toString() methods too, you just don't see them. This is a good example because it shows you what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Since `Object` has a `toString` method "checking to see if there is a toString() method" is a "little" erroneous...The gist of the answer is correct though ;) +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's a good point! I was trying to keep it as simple as possible, but I edited it to be more accurate :)

Comment: Probably, "checks to see if there is any `toString()` **overriden**" would have sounded better.

Answer (score 9):

`PrintStream.println(obj)` calls `obj.toString()`. (Or more precisely: it calls `String.valueOf(obj)`, which in turn calls `obj.toString()` unless `obj` is a null reference.)

See [the Javadoc for `java.io.PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29).

(Maybe what you're missing is that `toString` is actually a method on `java.lang.Object`? `Worker` and `Date` are merely overriding it. So *all* objects have that method, and JDK methods can rely on its existence. See [the Javadoc for `java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) for a list of all the methods that all objects have.)

Answer (score 3):

[`PrintStream.println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) explicitly makes a call to [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), which in turn calls `Object.toString()`, which is overridden in your two objects.