# why this java program is giving same output

Tags: java

```
class Frog
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public Frog(int id,String name)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return id+" "+name;
    }
}

public class Verify
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frog frog1=new Frog(4,"maggie");
        System.out.println(frog1);
    }
}
```

In the above code we get same result for passing "frog1" and "frog1.toString" in to `println` method why? Please anyone explain me. In the first case we are not explicitly invoking `toString` method.

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: What does [`PrintWriter.println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.Object-) do? How do you think it gets a `String` representation of an arbitrary `Object`?

Comment: Also, please stick to Java naming conventions, classes should be in `PascalCase`, `camelCase` is reserved for variables. Deviating this not only makes your code much harder to read, but also confuses automatic syntax highlighting.

Comment: Okay.sorry for inconvenience

Comment: duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object

Answer (score 2):

Because println(Object) calls intern the String.valueOf Method which 
calls in the end the toString method of the given Object.

See the documentation of PrintStream and String:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)

Here is the implementation of the println(Object) Method:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java

```
786 
787     public void println(Object x) {
788         String s = String.valueOf(x);
789         synchronized (this) {
790             print(s);
791             newLine();
792         }
793     }
```

Here is the implementation of the valueOf Method:
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/String-source.html

```
/**
1629:    * Returns a String representation of an Object. This is "null" if the
1630:    * object is null, otherwise it is <code>obj.toString()</code> (which
1631:    * can be null).
1632:    *
1633:    * @param obj the Object
1634:    * @return the string conversion of obj
1635:    */
1636:   public static String valueOf(Object obj)
1637:   {
1638:     return obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString();
1639:   }
```