# when println() is displaying an Object, which one of the Objects methods does println() call?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, static

When `println()` is displaying an `Object`, which one of the `Object`'s
methods does `println()` call?

- add()
- toString()
- equals()
- compareTo()
- String()

I'm Not Sure whether its `toString` or `String` can someone please clarify?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. I'm just a 12 year old. My parents are forcing me to go learn java at this prep school.

Comment: Look up the javadoc for `Object`. Which of the methods you've listed does it have and which doesn't it have. Go by elimination. Then look up what each one does.

Comment: Why dont you tell them I have tried!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647567/how-to-support-println-in-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the signature println(Object) the toString() method is being used to output the string representation of that object.

When toString() is called on an object you've defined it will cascade up the hierarchy of superclasses until reaching java.lang.Object given that there is no overridden toString() method in any intermediate superclasses or the initial class. Upon reaching java.lang.Object the system will call the base [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method which prints the String literal representation of that Object and is the reason why you will see some memory address in the output.

Answer (score 1):

None of them.
If you pass an Object to `println()` this

```
println(Object o)
```

will be called which calls the `String.valueOf(o)` actually.

But then `String.valueOf(o)` calls the `o.toString()`if the o is not null.

So you can say its `toString()` indirectly.

See
[println(java.lang.Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) and [valueOf(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))