# How toString() is automatically call inside println()

Tags: java, constructor

I just started learning Java. What I've learned about constructor is that :

1. It will automatically run when an object is initialized.
2. The name of the constructor has be the same as the class name.

Now, below is where I'm starting to get confused.

```
class Frog{

   public String toString() {
      return "Hello";
   }
}

public class App {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Frog frog1 = new Frog();
      System.out.println(frog1);
   }
}
```

My question :
Since `public String toString ()` is not a constructor, then why can it behave like constructor when I run the program. I thought It can only be run when I call it from the `App` class.

Comment: Since you have not defined a constructor for class Frog, Java compiler adds a "default constructor", that is automatically generated by the compiler. toString is automatically called for the frog1 Object constructed by the default constructor.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Short answer: public `frog1.toString()` method call is used **inside** `System.out.println(Object x)` call stack.

But how? Let's find it out together :)

Take a look at the `PrintStream` class (which instance is used as `System.out` field value by default) source code and its `println` implementation that accepts `Object` argument:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

And the `String`'s `valueOf` method for argument with `Object` type is:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

`obj` is `frog1` in your case, its `toString()` method is called and returns `"Hello"` String instance for the console output)

Comment: Exactly. `System.out.println(frog1)` implies a call to the `toString()` method. The same happens when you do something like `final String aString = "This is a " + frog1;`

Comment: but I don't specifically call frog1.toString(), I just call frog1.

Comment: what if I have multiple methods in the Frog class? Doesn't that mean I have to specify which methods to call?

Comment: @Bernard No, only the method with the exact name toString() will be called by `System.out.println(Object obj);` when you put in `frog1`, as explained by _Cootri_. Try renaming your toString() method to `test()` for example and see how the output of `System.out.println(frog1);` changes. Since you've got a method `public String toString()` you've basically overwritten the default Object's toString() method. (All classes automatically extend Object, enabling the use of some default Object-methods like toString() and getType().)

Comment: @Bernard What do you think will happen when `System.out.println(frog1);` gets executed? `Frog` is not `String` you see and hence it will invoke `toString()` on it. Since you have overridden the `toString()` method to return `Hello` it will print it on the console.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCruijssen, to be honest as a java beginner I can't really understand the example posted by Cootri until KevinCruijissen shed light on it with simpler explanation. And also thanks to all of bro's that have helped with additional explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The "toString" is not behaving like a constructor; the reason why it is being called is the second line in your `main` method:

```
  System.out.println(frog1);
```

This invokes `toString` on frog1.

Answer (score 1):

When you call PrintStream class print(obj) / println(obj) method then internally it called write method with arguement as String.valueOf(obj) shown below :

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Now String.valueOf(obj) does the task of calling to String method as shown below :

```
 /** 
 * Returns the string representation of the <code>Object</code> argument. 
 * 
 * @param   obj   an <code>Object</code>. 
 * @return  if the argument is <code>null</code>, then a string equal to 
 *          <code>"null"</code>; otherwise, the value of 
 *          <code>obj.toString()</code> is returned. 
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString() 
 */ 
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public String toString(){..}` is method of class `Object` , here overridden specifically for `Frog` class. This method returns object value representation. It's a method not a constructor. Please remember constructor cannot return value.

Valid constructor would be something like below:

```
 public Frog(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toString method overrides `Object.toString`

```
public String toString() {
      return "Hello";
}
```

So when call

```
 System.out.println(frog1);
```

It toString's the object to "hello"

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `toString` is to give some meaningful representation for your class. Something like description about the object or class can go inside `toString` method.

Whenever the object is used with any `String` referenced operations like `System.out.print` or `String s="abcd"+frog1;"` the content of `toString` will be returned.

If `toString` is not overridden it would return the object class and its hash code. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)

From your code,

- `Frog frog1 = new Frog();` => creates object `frog1` of type `Frog`.
- `System.out.println(frog1);` => outputs the `String` representation
  of the object `frog1`.

Hope it explains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand what "behaving like a constructor" means. The Frog constructor (the default one, because you haven't written one) is called when you do `new Frog()`. The call to `.toString()` is done automatically inside the call to `.println()`, which is in the line after the call to the constructor.

You may be getting confused because `toString()` is the only method you have declared. However, you are missing the knowledge that there is an implicit default constructor automatically in your class. If you were to type it out it would look like this:

```
public Frog() {
    // default constructor does nothing
}
```

It is that default constructor that is "behaving like a constructor". `toString()` is just behaving like a method that is being called by another method (the key thing being that `println(Object o)` is definitely certain that Object has a `toString()` method because it is part of the class definition).

Comment: The default constructor actually calls super(); automatically where applicable.