# "hidden" method to get the object "description"

Tags: java, tostring

I have an object and I can do:

> System.out.println(o);

Which is the "hidden" method called to get the object description ?

Always `toString()` or **does it depend from the object type** ?

Comment: In this case, it's always `toString`

Comment: It's not "hidden". It's declared in the `Object` class. you can override this method in any class you'd like to have a custom print String.

Comment: well if you override the `toString()` the `string` representation of that object will be called otherwise the `toString()` of the `Object` will be invoked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the toString() method being called when I print an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555771/why-is-the-tostring-method-being-called-when-i-print-an-object)

Comment: You can check this answer for an how-to implement/override the toString() method for your own needs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java